# GWT - Date Validation

Tags: gwt

can anyone tell me how to do date validation in GWT please. im passing date as String. it should to be converted to date format and its format is to be validated.

Comment: In which language? Java, C++, C#?

Comment: @user35443 GWT programming language is java !

Comment: Why do you want to validate converted string?

Answer (score 6):

```java
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

...
DateTimeFormat myDateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(...);
Date date = myDateTimeFormat.parseStrict(dateString);
```

`parseStrict()` throws an IllegalArgumentException for invalid date strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GWT Bean Validation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) pattern matching expression for String:

```
@Pattern( regexp = "some javascript regular expression" ) 
private String dateStr;
```

or this when you have date:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy")
private Date myStartDate;
```

I do not use this but you can see a complete sample in gwt-2.5.0 samples directory.

Have a nice time.